# How to add a custom button to the dhtmlx library toolbar?

Tags: angular, typescript, dhtmlx

In a project with Angular 16, I have a canvas to create a flow using the dhtmlx library, and I need to customize the toolbar that draws by default, and in addition, I need to capture the click event on that custom button.

The documentation of the dhtmlx library is poor and does not specify how to implement a custom button in Angular, in fact everything is made for javascript, the detail is that when a typed framework is used, it FAILS GREATLY and it is a headache to implement it. And yes, there are some "examples" in Angular, none of them work, when you download the projects and install them they do not run, they present a lot of compilation errors, and by the way they will only update up to Angular 10.

Comment: Could you please, clarify what dhtmlx component you are meaning?